# Command line prints should be saved in .txt file every 10min with multiple trail's

Tags: python-3.x, networking, automation, automated-tests, pytest

Import os
Import time

While True:
      Os.system("speed test.exe")
       Time.sleep(1000)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os 
import time

index = 0
while True: 
    os.system(f"speed test.exe > speed_text_{index}.txt") 
    index+=1
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: If i try this one, it will overwriting the previous .txt file. What i'm saying i want save nnew text file with every 10min Like as below. speed_text1.txt after 10mits speed_text2.txt so......loop continue

Comment: It's working fine but output results as.txt file not saving full MN